# Modified topological sort

Tags: sorting, greedy-algorithms, topological-ordering

I recently asked a [related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47901/finding-a-greedy-ordering-criteria) at the theoretical CS stack exchange, but I have modification to the problem that I think is a bit tougher. This seems like a better place anyways.

Let's define a "task" $T_k$ to be a tuple $(a_k, b_k, C)$, where $a_k$ is the amount of active time spent on a task, $b_k$ the inactive time, and $C$ a set of child tasks that cannot begin until this task is fully complete. For a given task, while I'm actively working on it I cannot do anything else. However, during the inactive period the task continues without my supervision and I can go do some other non-dependent task.

A good example is washing clothes: I might need $a_k = 5$ to load a washing machine, but then while the cycle runs ($b_k = 40$) I can go do something else with those 40 minutes. However, the tasks listed in $C$ cannot start until both the active and inactive parts have completed. So, using my existing example, I cannot run the dry cycle on my clothes until I've both loaded the washing machine and waited for the cycle to end.

So, given a set of tasks $T$ a question you could ask is: "What's the fastest I could complete a set of tasks?". In a way this is a topological sort, but there's also some weighting in there that I'm not sure how to navigate with existing topological sort algorithms. Perhaps there is a greedy way to pick the next node?

My question is this:

- Is there an algorithm to solve this problem (that isn't brute-force enumeration of course)
- Does this problem fall into an exist realm of research that I could investigate? Are there any introductory articles you could point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topological sorting would work if all $b_k$'s were zero.  Here is a way that takes into account the $b_k$'s.  Build a dag where each vertex is a task and there are edges from each task to its child tasks.  Then, use the following algorithm:

- Out of all sinks (vertices with out-degree zero), find the one whose $b_k$ value is smallest.  Output it, then delete it and all edges into it.
- Repeat, until all vertices have been output.

I believe this will output an optimal schedule, in reverse order (last task first).

Comment: This does match a my intuition. I asked a [related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47901/finding-a-greedy-ordering-criteria/47906?noredirect=1#comment106580_47906) (albeit in the wrong place), and the last task should be the one with the smallest $b_k$.

Comment: @ChipBell, I suggest seeing if you can prove it correct using the methods in https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/65284/755.  The comment on CSTheory seems to be hinting at that, for the easier case you posted there.