# Minimize Burst time left in CPU Scheduling in a fixed interval of time

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

I have $P$ different processes given along with their respective Burst time and arrival time. The time quantum is $1$ sec i.e. each process can only run for $1$ sec. There's a total time $F$ given for which computer will be available to perform these processes. Also for each process $P_i$ there exists a respective cost/sec for not performing it. There's no penalty for the waiting time. Penalty is on the basis of how much *percaentage* of burst time was left. Preemption is allowed.

For Eg- If $P=3$,$F=10$. $P_1$ has burst time of $9$ sec and penalty of $10/sec$ for $P_1$
Suppose the Gantt Chart comes out to be $|P_1P_2P_3P_1P_2P_2P_1P_1P_2P_1|$

Since $P_1$ was allowed to run for only $5$ sec till the end of all processes so total penalty will be $(9-5)*10= 40$ .

I have to schedule the process in so as to minimize the sum of penalty for all processes.

If priority was given instead of penalty for no-operation, I would simply select the process first on basis of arrival time and then on the basis of priority and then preempt the process like Preemptive Priority scheduling.

I tried it by using greedy approach. First I sort the jobs on basis of Arrival time and then if clash occurs then on the basis on cost so as to minimize the sum of total cost incurred. I choose the job with min Arrival time and maximum Cost.

Is there any more optimal and efficient way to minimize the total cost ?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Are you looking for an algorithm to find the optimal schedule?  Is this a streaming/on-line situation (where you are only told about the existence of a process when it arrives) or a batch situation (where you know about all processes in advance)?  Do you care about how efficient the algorithm is?  Can $P$ be considered a small constant for purposes of running time analysis?  What algorithm design paradigms have you already tried?  it sounds like you are investigating greedy algorithms; for that, take a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755.

Comment: @D.W. This is a batch situation i.e. all information is known before hand.  And I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find the optimal schedule. $P$ is fairly large for practical purposes i.e. around $10^3$. I have updated my answer to what I have tried.

Comment: I suggest you use the techniques in https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755 to try to determine if your method produces the optimal solution: implement and use random testing, and if it always seems optimal, try to prove it.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks, I have tried random testing. My solution seems to be efficient but not optimal. I think the greedy solution may be not be optimal here.