# With restrictions, can the knapsack puzzle be solved with a greedy algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms, knapsack-problems

I know that with the knapsack problem in general, there is no known greedy algorithm to solve it. But, say we add the following constraints:

• All items have values equal to their weights (for all $i$, $w_i = v_i$)

• The weights are all powers of 2 (for all $w_i$ there exists $n ∈ N$ such that $w_i$ = $2^n$).

Now, a knapsack problem with the following constraints can have a greedy algorithm that selects the heaviest item which can currently fit in the knapsack until no item remaining can fit.

---

Will this work or is there really no way the constrained knapsack problem can be solved with a greedy algorithm?

Comment: With weights equal to values, knapsack becomes a [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Comment: Have you tried proving your algorithm correct?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755