# Greedy Solution for Selecting Prefix Sum

Tags: algorithms, sorting, greedy-algorithms

Given $n$ arrays. Each has size of $h$. Let $a_{i, j} \in \mathbb{I}$ be the $i$-th element of $j$-th array. You can select at most $k$ numbers from all arrays but if you pick $a_{i, j}$, you have to pick $a_{1, j}, a_{2, j}, \dots, a_{i-1, j}$ as well. Each element can only be picked once. Find maximum sum of elements.

My greedy solution is : Let $p_{i, j}$ be $\sum_{x=1}^{i} a_{x, j}$. Sort a list of $\frac{p_{i, j}}{i}$ for all $i$ and $j$ in descending order. Then iterate through the list and check each value whether we have included the prefix sum of this array into our final answer or not. If no and $h \geq j$, we include it in the final answer, subtract $i$ from $h$, and mark $j$ as included. If yes and $j >$ the index of the previous one, we do the same thing just the part extended from the previous one.

Is this solution optimal or is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you pick the same number multiple times?

Comment: No, you can only pick each number once.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your greedy algorithm may return elements whose sum is not the maximum. For example, let $n=h=k=2$ and 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1\\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Your algorithm will pick 3 and 1. The optimal elements should be 3 and 2.

The natural approach to this problem is [dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info).

Here are the subproblems.

For nonnegative integers $t$ and $j$ such that $0\le j\le n$ and $0\le t \le \min(nh, t)$, find $dp(t,j)$, the maximal sum of $t$ elements from the first $j$ arrays where all elements selected from the same array must be a prefix of that array. The wanted maximum sum is the maximum number of all $dp(t,j)$.

In order to select $t$ elements from the first $j$ arrays, we can select $i$ elements from the $j$-th array and $t-i$ elements from the first $j-1$ arrays for some $i$, $0\le i\le \min(t,h)$. Hence we have the following recurrence relation.

$$ dp(t,j) = \max_{0\le i\le \min(t,h)}\left(dp(t-i, j-1) + \sum_{1\le k\le i}a_{k,j}\right)$$

The base cases and the boundary cases can be figured out easily.

Comment: A nice solution to a nice problem. I have passed some time on this problem wondering if it was polymonial. And if I am correct, this is a O(kn²).