# Job Scheduling with deadline with $nlogn$ algorithm

Tags: greedy-algorithms, binary-search, mergesort

We know that there is a Greedy algorithm for scheduling of $n$ jobs which each job has its own deadline and profit.

In greedy algorithm, we sort the set by their profit descendant, And if a job can add to a `possible set` of jobs, we add it to the set.

A job can be added to the set, if it starts before its deadline and each work need 1 time slot for doing.

Is there any $O(nlogn)$ algorithm for this problem as follows?

- Sorting the set by their profit using merge sort in $O(nlogn)$
- Add the first job to the possibility set.
- For remain jobs, add the job to the set of its deadline is less than its index in possibility set.
- We have to remain the `possible set` sorted. Then for each new coming job, we can add it to the set using `binary search` in $O(logn)$

Total cost of the above algorithm is $O(nlogn)+O(n)*O(logn)=O(nlogn)$

Is this algorithm correct?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "set" ? It seems there are different types of set in your explanation.

Comment: We discourage "is my algorithm correct?" questions, as the only possible answer is yes/no, which is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.  The way to tell whether your algorithm is correct is to prove it correct.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755.  I suggest you give that a try, and if you get stuck at any particular point, ask about that specific aspect of the proof.