# Algorithm of split graph $G=(V,E)$ to 2 groups that at least half of the edges are between the groups

Tags: algorithms, graphs, greedy-algorithms

Can someone remind me the algorithm that split vertex of graph to 2 groups that at least half of the edges are external, I mean between the groups. As I remember it was a greedy algorithm, each time chosen the vertex with highest number of edges, or something similar

Comment: BTW, there is a simple answer to this on StackExchange itself: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126935/using-a-greedy-algorithm-to-find-a-cut-s-which-at-least-half-of-the-edges-cut?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The solution and the analysis is given in Section 6.2.1 and 6.3 of the Book: [Probability and Computing
Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis](http://read.pudn.com/downloads511/ebook/2123271/Probability%20and%20Computing%20-%20%20Randomized%20Algorithms%20and%20Probabilistic%20Analysis.pdf)

Sometimes it is better to refer to a book rather than formulating an answer by ourselves :)