# Finding an optimal solution for the following problem

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

This is an intriguing question given by my friend for which I want to find an optimal solution:

> Each week, you can choose to work ONLINE $(ON)$ or in person $(WR)$ in
> your department's office. If you attend work online in week $i$, you
> will spend $ON_i$ hours; otherwise, if you attend work offline in the
> department, you will spend $WR_i$ hours. However, if you work online
> in week $i$ and convert to offline mode in week $i + 1$ or vice versa,
> you will have to spend an additional $H$ hours to transfer from online
> to offline since you will need to go to the office to request a change
> of mode. The amount of time it takes to switch is fixed, i.e. $H$
> hours.
>
> Create a schedule for working for $n$ weeks, with each
> week consisting of either online $(ON)$ or offline $(WR)$ attendance.
> The sum of the time we spent on each of the $n$ months, plus $H$ hours
> changeover time for each time you switch ways of attending work,
> equals the total credit hours of a plan. In either mode, the plan can
> commence.
>
> Given the value of switching time H, and sequence of values $\{ON_1,
> > ON_2, . . . , ON_n\} and \{WR_1, WR_2, . . . , WR_n \}$, devise an
> optimal minimum credit hour schedule.

To solve this question, according to me, we can create a greedy algorithm and I came up with the following greedy algorithm:

```
for i = 1 to n
if ONi < WRi
   Output “Online in Month i”
else
   Output “Offline in Month i”
end
```

I would like to know if there is any other, that is a better algorithm that takes as input n, H and sequences $\{ON_1,
> ON_2, . . . , ON_n\} and \{WR_1, WR_2, . . . , WR_n \}$, and returns the required credit hour optimally.

Comment: Hint: To find a counterexample, you can just choose a very high value for $H$.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755

Comment: You can try envisioning the problem as a 'shortest path' calculation instead