# Proving correctness for greedy algorithm in string removal problem

Tags: strings, greedy-algorithms, correctness-proof

Problem Statement:
You are given a string s and two integers x and y. You can perform two types of operations any number of times.
Remove substring "ab" and gain x points.
For example, when removing "ab" from "cabxbae" it becomes "cxbae".
Remove substring "ba" and gain y points.
For example, when removing "ba" from "cabxbae" it becomes "cabxe".
Return the maximum points you can gain after applying the above operations on s.

A greedy algorithm solves this problem in O(n). The greedy algorithm works by eliminating all pairs with a higher scoring value before removing pairs of a lower scoring value. Can anyone present a proof for the correctness of a greedy algorithm here. I have been trying, and I cannot convince myself.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Copying without attribution constitutes plagiarism, and [plagiarism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not ok](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, for trying to prove correctness.  We have a guide on how to approach such proofs: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755.

Answer (score 1):

(For the greedy algorithm described to be optimal, it is also necessary to assume that $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative.)

Without loss of generality, we can assume $y \ge x$.

Suppose to the contrary that the greedy algorithm is not optimal. Then there exist some string (possibly an intermediate state) containing a consecutive pair $\mathrm{ba}$ whose removal is suboptimal. Consider what happens to those letters in the optimal solution.

- If neither is removed in the optimal solution, then also removing the pair gives a better solution – a contradiction.
- If exactly one of those letters is removed in the optimal solution, then modifying the solution by first removing the $\mathrm{ba}$ pair, and omitting whatever removal applied to one of them later, gives another solution that is at least as good, contradicting the assumed suboptimality of removing the $\mathrm{ba}$ pair. (Because the other member of the pair was never removed in the optimal solution, this change works, in that it cannot break any later removals.)
- If both of those letters are removed in the optimal solution, that means they are paired up with an $\mathrm{a}$ on the left and a $\mathrm{b}$ on the right. In this case, we can modify the solution by first removing the $\mathrm{ba}$ pair, and later pairing up and removing those other $\mathrm{a}$ and $\mathrm{b}$, which is again a contradiction.