# Why can we solve this problem by a greedy algorithm?

Tags: greedy-algorithms

https://atcoder.jp/contests/past202004-open/tasks/past202004_f
I am trying to solve the following problem:

> We have $N$ tasks. Let today be Day $1$. You can do the $i$-th task on or after Day $A_i$, and finishing the task gives you $B_i$ points.
>
> Each day, starting with today, you choose one task and finish it. For each integer $k$ from $1$ through $N$, find the maximum total number of points that can be earned in the $k$ days starting with today.
>
> It is guaranteed that there are at least $k$ tasks that you can do in the first $k$ days for each integer $k$ from $1$ through $N$.

I know we can solve this problem by a greedy algorithm.
But why can we solve this problem by a greedy algorithm?

Comment: Simply because your goal here is to maximize some reward/number of points and a greedy algorithm makes the optimal choice at each step  i (each day in your case)  hoping to find the global optimal way to solve the entire problem.  So  let me ask you why can't we solve it with greedy? there is no reason not to...

Comment: It requires proof. If the greedy algorithm is optimal, then you can prove that it is so.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755

Comment: Because the problem can be represented as a matroid...

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.