# prove the correctness of greedy algorithm on interger optimize

Tags: optimization, greedy-algorithms

Let $n$ and $r$ be positive integers. For i = 1,2,...,n, let $f_i$ be a univariate real-valued function defined in the integer domain and let $f_i(x_i)$ be $-\infty$ for negative integer $x_i$.

Any non-negative integer solution $(x1,...,x_n)$ that satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = r$ is called a feasible solution. In addition, a feasible solution that maximizes the objective function $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$ is called an optimal solution and the objective function value at the solution
is called the optimal value. This problem is expressed as follows.

$$
(P)
\begin{cases}
\text{Maximize}& \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)\\
\text{subject to}&  \displaystyle  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = r \\
 & x_i \text{ is a non-negative integer, i=1,...,n}
\end{cases}
$$

let there be a greedy algorithm $A_G$ to (P)

$d_i(a) := f_i(a)-f_i(a-1)$, assume $d_i(a)$ is non-increasing in terms of a.

Step 0: for $i=1,2,...,n$ ,set $x_i$ <- 0

Step 1: Repeat r times: Let y be any index $i$ that maximizes $d_i(x_i+1)$ among $i=1,2,...,n$, set $x_y$ += 1.

Question:

How can I prove

1. Let $(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)$ be a feasible solution. Show that it is an optimal solution of (P) if and only if the following condition holds.

$$
\max_{i=1,2,..,n} d_i(x_i^*+1) \le \min_{i=1,2,..,n}d_i(x_i^*)
$$

2. the greedy algorithm outputs an optimal solution of (P).

---

I've tested some inputs, and find that it's just making the "current largest step", since assuming $d_i(a)$ is non-increasing in terms of a, so it meets the need of a greedy algorithm. But I don't know how to express it into a prove.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755