# What would be an efficient algorithm that finds the maximum number of party people?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, greedy-algorithms

You want to organize a party and invite as many of your N friends as possible so that the following condition is met: at a party, everyone invited must know at least three other guests and must not be familiar with at least three other guests. The input to the problem is number N and the list of pairs (i, j) where i and j know each other. What would be an efficient algorithm that implements the above mentioned and what's the complexity? Could I use some greedy approach?

Comment: We're not particularly looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Typically, there are only a few sensible greedy algorithms worth considering; have you tried checking whether any of them work, using https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755?  Why do you think an efficient algorithm exists?

Comment: If A knows B, does B know A?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It's actually quite simple.

(Yes, that's all the hint you need).

Comment: The hint indeed helped me:)