# Optimality in greedy task

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

There is a well-known problem of the best time to buy and sell stock. Assume now we have two arrays, *SELL* and *BUY*. Each time *SELL[i]* > *BUY[i]*. Assume we have initial budget *B*, and we can buy any amount of stock bounded by our budget. We want to determine the maximum profit we can reach using the best strategy.

I've tried to use a greedy approach:

1. Set **sell_price** as MAX_FLOAT
2. while *BUY[i]* < **sell_price**: update **sell_price** as current minimum *SELL[:i]* and increase *i*. If *BUY[i]* > **sell_price**. Buy maximum stocks with **sell_price** and immediately sell them by *BUY[i]*, then update budget and calculate profit.
3. Repeat 1-2.

I am unsure if this greedy approach is the best. It seems to be knapsack problem, but I guess it's much simplier.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755