# Given m intervals and an array of integers, your task is to minimize the number of operations in which you can make the elements of the array nonposit

Tags: greedy-algorithms, intervals, segment-trees

You are given the number $m$ and $m$ intervals of the form $a_i, b_i, v_i$, where $a_i<=b_i$ and $v_i>0$ and also a number $n$ and an array $s$ of length $n$, where $s_i>0$. In one operation you can choose an interval say $j$ and decrease the values of $s_i$ by 1, where $a_j<=i<=b_j$, and you can choose interval $j$ at most $v_j$ times. The task is to find the minimum number of operations required to make all elements of $s$ non-positive.

My approach is some greedy where I sort the intervals by the starting point, and then iterate over the values of $s$ and if $s_i$ is positive I repeatedly find the first starting interval that contains index i and apply the minimum necesary ammount of operations. The way I do the update it is with segment trees. Overall, I am not convinced this greedy approach is right.

Comment: Is the question whether your greedy approach works?

Comment: What is your question? We are a Q&A site, so we require you to articulate a specific question (please don't make us guess).  Normally, a question ends with a "?".  See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755

Comment: the question is what is the correct approach to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your greedy approach does not work.
Consider the $m=2$ intervals $[1,2]$ and $[2,3]$ each of which can only be used once. Let the array $s$ of $n = 3$ elements be $\langle 0, 1, 1 \rangle$.

Your approach uses $2$ operations, namely it chooses first the interval $[1,2]$ and then the interval $[2,3]$. However, the minimum number of operations needed to solve the problem is $1$ (i.e., simply choose $[2,3]$).

Comment: what would be a correct greedy approach or is this problem's solution even greedy?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a quite simple greedy algorithm that lets us pick one interval after the other in an optimal way. At any point we do the following:

1. Find the smallest i with $s_i > 0$. If there is no such i then we are done. If there is a smallest i, then we need to pick an interval containing i at some point, so we pick it right now.
2. Among all the intervals $[a_j .. b_j]$ with $v_j > 0$ containing i, that is with $a_j ≤ i ≤ b_j$, we pick the one with the largest $b_j$ and remove it, then we go back to Step 1. Removing an interval with a larger $b_j$ is never less good than removing one with a smaller $b_j$, so this will lead to an optimal solution if one exists.

What happens with Steven's counter example against the original algorithm? We have $s_2 > 0$ and $s_3 > 0$. In Step 1 $i = 2$ is the smallest i. Both intervals contain $i = 2$, but for the interval [2 .. 3], $b_j = 3$ has the largest value, so we pick the interval [2 .. 3], decrease $s_2$ and $s_3$, and now we have no i with $s_i > 0$ anymore.

Comment: it makes sense, thank you very much for your help