# Greedy algorithm for minimising the number of encountered obstacles from multiple start points to single endpoint in a grid

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem, greedy-algorithms

I am given a $N$ x $M$ sized grid and $K$ start points $S = (s_1, s_2, .. s_k)$ where each $s_k = (x_k,y_k)$ representing the position on the grid. I am also given a single endpoint $(x_{end}, y_{end})$. Some cells of the grid contain obstacles which are undesirable to pass through.

Given that we have a routine `getPaths(x_k, y_k)` to compute all paths from each $(x_k,y_k)$ to $(x_{end}, y_{end})$, I need to choose a path for each $(x_k, y_k)$ to $(x_{end}, y_{end})$ such that the total number of obstacles encountered along the union of paths is minimised.

I was thinking if the following greedy algorithm would give an optimal answer. The psuedo steps are as follows:

```
U = {}
allPaths = flatten([getPaths(x_i, y_i) for all i = 1, ... k])
obstacleSet = set()
while U does not contain all k paths
    // best path that when merged with obstacle Set returns the least number of obstacles
    [bestPath, obstacleSet] = findBestPath(allPaths, obstacleSet)

    // filter from allPaths paths which contain the source of `bestPath`
    allPaths = filter(allPaths, bestPath.source)

    // add best path to U
    U.add(bestPath)
end
```

Would greedy algorithm be able to give an optimal solution in this scenario ?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755

Comment: No. This greedy algorithm does not give the optimal answer. Try to create a counter example with three start vertices. For each vertex there might exists an exclusive path with $2$ obstacles each. Total obstacles will be $6$. However, there might exits a path with $3$ obstacles that is shared by all the three vertices. Then, the total obstacles will be $3$.