# Greedy Maximum Bipartite Matching

Tags: greedy-algorithms, bipartite-matching

To find the maximum matching on a bipartite graph, I propose the following greedy algorithm:
At each iteration, pick an unmatched vertex with the smallest degree and match it to one of it's neighbours if possible. Remove the 2 matched vertices and all of it's edges from the graph and repeat till the graph is empty.

I've tried finding a counter example for this greedy algorithm, but am not able to come up with one.

Could someone provide me with a counter example? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried implementing it and using random testing?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59964/755.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a counter example on [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/123083). However if it's *complete* bipartite matching, we can use the greedy Nobel winning [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Shapley_algorithm) in Economics.